# main.window() or what?

Tags: javascript

I wrote some JS code, but I can´t anything out. I just goes blank.
Is it because I don´t have a main functions for my functions?

```
  <html>
<head><title>JavaScript</title></head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Redovisning av Inlämningsuppgift 4" + "<br/>");
        document.write("Informationssystem 1-30, Malmö Högskola, dec 2010" + "<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("Usman Rajab, datorid: CDA08028");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        document.write("==========================================================" + "<br/>");
        document.write("UPPGIFT NR 2" + "<br/>");
        document.write("============");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        var loan = 1000000;
        var amoyear = 6000;
        for( var answer = 1; amoyear * answer <= loan; answer++)
        {
        }
        document.write("Ett lån på 1000000 kr är betalt efter " + Math.ceil(answer) + " år om amorteringen är 500 kr/mån. ");

        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        document.write("==========================================================" + "<br/>");
        document.write("UPPGIFT NR 3" + "<br/>");
        document.write("============");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        antalAr(1000000,1000);
        antalAr(1500000,500);
        function antalAr(lan, amortering)
        {
            amoyear = amortering * 12;
            for( var answer = 1; amoyear * answer <= loan; answer++){}
            document.write("Ett lån på " + lan + " kr är betalt efter " + Math.ceil(answer) + "år om amorteringen är på " + amortering +" kr/mån." + "</br>");
        }

        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        document.write("==========================================================" + "<br/>");
        document.write("UPPGIFT NR 4" + "<br/>");
        document.write("============");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        for(var i = 1000; i<= 3000; i+=1000)
        {
            antalAr(1200000,i);
        }

        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        document.write("==========================================================" + "<br/>");
        document.write("UPPGIFT NR 5" + "<br/>");
        document.write("============");
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("<br/>");

        function Calc(){            
            for(int i=-1; i<13; i++)
        {
            alert(monthName(i));
        }
        }
        function monthName(a)
        {
            if(a == 0)
                return 'Januari';
            else if(a == 1)
                return 'Februari';
            else if(a == 2)
                return 'Mars';
            else if(a == 3)
                return 'April';
            else if(a == 4)
                return 'Maj';
            else if(a == 5)
                return 'Juni';
            else if(a == 6)
                return 'Juli';
            else if(a == 7)
                return 'Augusti';
            else if(a == 8)
                return 'September';
            else if(a == 9)
                return 'Oktober';
            else if(a == 10)
                return 'November';
            else if(a == 11)
                return 'December';
            else 
                return 'undefined';
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh dear. `document.write` should die.

Comment: The `getMonth` thing looks like it was copied straight from dailywtf...

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel - LOL! So true! @SHUMA - `var months = ['Januari', Februari', ...]; return months[a];`

Comment: not preaching for doug or anything but checking your code in www.jslint.com can only help you in those situations

Comment: @m_oLogin SHUMA would get more warnings from JSLint about `document.write` than anything else...

Comment: that's not such a bad thing :) though it's true

Answer (score 2):

Test to see if any JavaScript errors are occurring.  In some browsers, once a JavaScript error takes place, script execution stops.  <strike>In fact, I see some errors just by inspecting your code (you call `antalAr` before it has been declared)</strike>

**Edit:**

In IE, the `for(int i=-1; i<13; i++)` line is where the first error occurs.  (`int` is not valid in JavaScript).  Replacing `int` with `var` allows the script to run on my machine.

I'd recommend using IE with script debugging enabled or Firebug during any JavaScript development.

Comment: ... `antalAr` is a function statement... it gets executed before everything else is run, therefore it's available from the start (in the scope it was defined in)

Comment: The use of `int` instead of `var` (A mistake I've made myself when switching languages) is the cause of SHUMA's failure.

Comment: I try this, but it dosent work: function Calc(){   
   for(var i=-1; i<13; i++)
  {
   document.write( i + ":" monthName(i));
  }
  }

Comment: "Works" for me (there is no runtime exception).  `Calc` isn't actually called anywhere in your script, though.  Is that the problem?

Comment: JSFiddling is fcuk awesome! Thanks jball, And Jacob: Yeah, you are right =).